# Calling a function from terminal without export from sources file

Tags: bash, function, source

Have added a number of functions which I source from my `.bashrc`.  For instance, I use

```
export -f calc
```

I also have another function `usage_calc` where I comment out the export call

```
# export -f usage_calc
```

But I can still call `usage_calc`.  What is happening?

Comment: You have a executable, alias or shell function called `myfunc2` which calls `myfunc`.  Without more information there is nothing more anyone can tell you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Role of export -f statement when creating functions in bash\_profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463344/role-of-export-f-statement-when-creating-functions-in-bash-profile)

Comment: It does not really address the requirements of `export` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `bash` as your shell. The function is defined in or via your `.bashrc`, which makes the function available to your shell. The `export` has no relevance

Comment: Eons I go, I had to include `export -f` so that function names are recognised as functions.  Now I am clueless on when I need to call export and when there is no need for it.

Comment: @Aardvark for functions (and variables generally), don't use `export` unless you've a specific requirement

Comment: Could you list me a few instances when `export` is needed.  I think I need to use export on some functions.

Comment: If you want to use a function in a bash shell that does not first call .bashrc

Comment: And now it hit me.  If you define a shell function in your .bashrc file, it will not be available to scripts, only to your interactive shell.  Is there some good practice for this?

Comment: @Aardvark yes. Don't have your scripts assume too much about the environment. If I'm writing for a multiuser system I can't assume that someone's got my functions defined in their `.bashrc`

Comment: Not assuming the functions are defined in the .bashrc requires sourcing the file dependencies before using the functionalities defined in them.  This means that generally speaking, one does not export function names, but one may export specific variables for the software packages that need them.